# AdMob view will not show in GameScene

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, admob

so far I've been tugging at this for hours, and I've looked at every possible other tutorial on Stack Overflow, but I just haven't found the answer, so:
    I'm having trouble displaying an Ad using AdMob on my SpriteKit game that I've just made. The technique I'm using is creating a view in the main storyboard, referencing it in my ViewController, and then loading a banner ad into it. It hasn't worked and I honestly just can't figure out why. my code is as follows.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        bannerView.delegate = self as? GADBannerViewDelegate
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1718155263015340/4071220536"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self


        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ "a97e7f48344dd22c501872c61a342a97" ]
        bannerView.load(request)



        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
```

and it continues to show some other stuff that's built in. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your view controller does not conform to `GADBannerViewDelegate`. Change `class GameViewController: UIViewController {` to `class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {` and replace `bannerView.delegate = self as? GADBannerViewDelegate` with `bannerView.delegate = self` (since casting is superfluous).

Comment: still didn't work... I know the code is right to request and load the ad, but I think it's hidden somehow

Comment: ah! Got it. So it turns out that in adMob there was a warning stating that I needed to fix some information, and after that it worked like a charm. If anyone has trouble with this in the future, I recommend checking your debug logs, and if that doesn't work, then check admob.